# Слушатель закрытия Activity

Tags: java, android, activity

У меня есть класс, который создаёт Activity в некоторых ситуациях, но он не наследуется от Activity. Как мне сделать так, что бы при закрытии Activity в классе который запустил активность исполнился некоторый участок кода.

P.S. Нужно что то на подобие: слушателя на закрытие Activity.

UPD:Запуск активности

```
public class DownloadAndUpdateCategories {

private List<Category> mCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
private RealmConfiguration mConfig = Realm.getDefaultConfiguration();
private Realm mRealm = Realm.getInstance(mConfig);

public DownloadAndUpdateCategories() {
    downloadAndUpdateCategories();
}

private void downloadAndUpdateCategories() {
    ServerAPI service = RetrofitDto.getRetrofitDto().create(ServerAPI.class);
    Call<List<Category>> call = service.getCategories("user");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Category>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@Nonnull Call<List<Category>> call,@Nonnull Response<List<Category>> response) {
            mCategoryList = response.body();
            updateCategories();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@Nonnull Call<List<Category>> call, @Nonnull Throwable t) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "No data was received from the server. Throwable = " + t);

            RealmResults<Category> categories = mRealm.where(Category.class).findAll();
            if(categories.size() == 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(BaseApplication.context, ErrorConnectionActivity.class);
                ((Activity) BaseApplication.context).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean updateCategories() {
    RealmAsyncTask task = Realm.getInstanceAsync(mConfig, new Realm.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@Nonnull Realm realm) {
            realm.beginTransaction();
            try {
                realm.insertOrUpdate(mCategoryList);
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Data successfully updated");
            } catch (RealmException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Data not updated. Error = " + e);
            }
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
}
```

По сути сама активность:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_connection);
        setTitle("Нет подключения к интернету");

        btRepeat = findViewById(R.id.btRepeat);
        btRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Не очень понятно что у вас за задача. И что вы имеете в виду под `при его закрытии`. Вы про закрытие активити или этого класса? Если второе - то у классов нет закрытий. Попробуйте подробнее описать задачу и имеющийся код хорошо бы привести в вопросе)

Comment: Не вижу смысла приводить onCreate из Activity, который содержит кнопку. И класс в котором идёт вызов этого активити. Это обычный DTO который показывает ошибку (создавая новое активити) при отсутствии интернета. Такое ТЗ, что ошибка должна быть в отдельном экране, с кнопкой повторить. Хотел сделать через startActivityForResult(), но не знаю как вызвать метод onActivityResult() в классе не являющимся (Activity).

Comment: Поясните хотя бы что значит `вызов этого активити` - так вы называете запуск активити через Intent? Если да, то у вас, очевидно, контекст есть. Если он есть и он это актвити, то скастуйте его к ней и вызывайте `startActivityForResult`. А вообще без кода и по вашим словам мне кажется что вы что-то неправильно делаете.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, код появился, вроде.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, проблема не запустить активность, а получить результат и обратный вызов.

Comment: @Valeriy, вы можете сделать ваш класс синглтоном и в вашей активити перед её завершением вызвать нужный метод вашего класса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я пробовал делать Activity "Singleton-ом", ведь его мне нужно использовать в разных участках кода. Но я не смог придумать как его реализовать. Или нужно делать все классы синглетоном в которых я использую данное активити или делать какой-то промежуточный класс?

Comment: @Valeriy, синглтоном сделайте `DownloadAndUpdateCategories` - вам ведь его метод надо вызывать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне нужно показать экран об ошибки подключения к интернету с одной кнопкой "повторить". Такой экран может возникать в разных участках программы и `DownloadAndUpdateCategories` у меня не единственное место и вызывать нужно тот метод который соответствует тому месту в программе где и произошла ошибка. Что бы не копировать идентичный код (В лице активити с одной кнопкой), реализовать слушатель, который определяет закрытие активности и выполняет вызов метода `downloadAndUpdateCategories();`. Такие слушатели реализовывать в каждом месте где может быть выведена такая ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

startActivityForResult() подойдет?

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=ru

Comment: Спасибо, но нет. Там писал в комментариях что я бы его с радостью использовал бы, но: проблемой является не создать Активность, а определить когда она закроется, соответственно в такой реализации как вы предлагаете возникает вопрос: как использовать метод `onActivityResult()` в классе который не является наследником класса `Activity`.

Comment: а если в onResume выполнять? каким то флагом проверяйте, что это onResume не после onCreate и все

Comment: Я думал об этом, так я сделал когда мне нужно было иконки в тулбаре прятать, но здесь нужно что бы было какое либо событие, которое вызывало бы мой метод. Это событие должно реагировать на закрытие Activity.